# How should I organize this code (OOP, interfacing)

Tags: java, oop, interface

I'm trying to create a structure for a graph. So far I'm trying to make up how I should create some classes for edges.

Edges in graphs can be

Regular,
Directed, Weighted (or any of the above).

So what do you think is the best way to organize this class, I was thinking of creating a interface IEdge, and then create the classes

```
public interface IEdge{
}

public class DirectedEdge implements IEdge{}
public class WeightedEdge implements IEdge{}
```

But now I've come with a problem, it's not very flexible, what if I want the following

```
public class DirectedWeightedEdge implements IEdge{}
```

How would you code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no OOP exercise -- I mean, use logic first and then look at the patterns. A directed and an undirected graphs are very different beasts. A directed edge has a start and an end, an undirected one has just two nodes. You may call them start and end in order to get a common base, but there's no such thing as *directedness* to be added to an edge.

At the same time, edges may have colors, weights, prices, length, capacity, etc. Do you really want to implement `ColoredWeightedPricedHavingLenghtCapacityLimitedEdge`? Or do you want to use 5 decorators? I hope you don't.

My first point is that the "directedness" doesn't fit nicely in any pattern. You could use an attribute "isDirected" or whatever, and maybe you don't need it at all as most graphs don't mix different kinds of edges. So a single attribute per `Graph` should do. Quite often, an undirected edge gets represented by a pair of two directed ones.

My second point is that things like weight should in general not be forcibly put in the edge. Using a `Map<IEdge, Double>` as a property of the `Graph` does a better job. You can still use objects like Edge and Node, which precludes confusing them (what could easily happen in C where you'd probably use their `id`s), but keep their properties external.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you explicitly create edges at all? In every graph implementation I've done so far edges existed just implicitly in the node objects. In every node you'll want an array of adjacent nodes - if you need them weighted just add an integer.

Direction follows quite naturally from that as well (well a bidirectional graph is easily represented by a unidirectional..). Obviously you could also save them as an adjacency matrix if the graph is small enough - that's quite nice for parallel algorithms.. but then if performance is important we're talking about sizes where the complete matrix is unuseable.

Edit: After comments I think I should clarify that a bit: Using an Edge class that keeps additional information about the edge (color, weight) is fine, but I'd always use it as part of a specific node: I.e. something like this - in C I'd use a struct for that.

```
class Node {
    List<Edge> children;

    class Edge {
        int weight;
        Color color;
        Node dest;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a software that has to display the graphs, and edges have colours for example. Would you stuff that into the node too? Surely not.

Comment: No I would use a Edge class but I would never differentiate between directed/undirected or anything else. Just a node and the additional information (as I said for the weighted graph) - which is a edge implementaiton you're right, maybe I misunderstood his intention with the Edge class.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting idea, but an edge always belongs to exactly two nodes. So in your implementation an edge would be represented by two edge objects. It might be effective but it doesn't sound too OO to me.

Comment: Yeah you're right it's probably not 100% OO and you always create a directed graph (which means creating two edges for bidirectional graphs). So maybe there's a better (respectively a cleaner/more elegant solution), but I can vouch that it's at least efficient and works well for large scale graphs and a wide range of algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a mixture of inheritance and the aforementioned decorator pattern.

Directed and undirected edges behave quite differently, they are mandatory and are mutually exclusive. Therefore they should be the only two implementations of the `Edge` interface.

Weights, however, are just something you can bolt on an existing edge, so the decorator pattern is the most appropiate for them.

But to return to square one for a moment, depending on how much shared code directed and undirected edges will have, maybe an `Edge` abstract class would be better than an interface. Of course the "correct" solution is to have both: an interface, implemented by an abstract class, extended by two concrete classes. But in this case this sounds like overengineering.

Answer (score 0):

Use of the decorator pattern may be appropriate here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

basically, you would have a base class implementing IEdge, and DirectedEdgeDecorator and WeightedEdgeDecorator classes that also implement the IEdge interface. The *Decorator classes would 'wrap' the base edge class and add the additional functionality to it. With this pattern, you can stack multiple decorators on an IEdge, one over the other to modify its behavior in different ways.

Comment: I disagree. At any time, you can decorate the base class by *either* DirectedEdgeDecorator *or* WeightedEdgeDecorator. You can decorate the decorated class, but then you loose the access to the underlying decoration. You can't use the decorators dynamically in the way you can use e.g. a DataInputStream, since the decorators need state. Moreover, there is no such thing as adding *Directedness* to an edge. A directed edge is a very different beast.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the edge information from the adjacency information. That means you don't duplicate edge data and instead store them in an adjacency list.

```
public class Node<TEdge> {
    class AdjacencyInfo {
       Node<TEdge> node;
       TEdge edge;

       public AdjacencyInfo(Node<TEdge> node, TEdge edge) {
          // ....
       }
    }

    bool isDiGraph; 
    List<AdjacencyInfo> adj;
    ///.... constructor, other methods

    public TEdge ConnectTo(Node<TEdge> node) {
       TEdge e = new TEdge();
       AdjacencyInfo a0 = new AdjacencyInfo(node, e);
       this.adj.Add(a0);
       if (!isDiGraph) {
           AdjacencyInfo a1 = new AdjacencyInfo(this, e);
           node.adj.Add(a1);
       }
       return e; // return the edge so caller is able to set edge properties (weight, color, etc)
    }
}
```

Something like this should work and clearly solves the directed/non-directed problem. I'm not aware of how much of this can be accomplished using Java generics as they're mostly unusable for other things than avoiding typecasts in containers, but in case you need to be able to handle only weighted edges then you can avoid generics by setting the weight to 1 or whatever makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

one type, with two properties

```
type Edge
    boolean directed = false;
    number  weight = 1;
```